# Deploy SSIS Package with SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, installation-package

I am working with SSIS 2008. My package has two connections (both are SQL Server Authentication). One is source connection and other is destination. I want to deploy this package in SQL Server and have a SQL job run this package. I need a installer for this as well so that the package can be installed on any machine. I am not sure how to expose the connection strings and what would be the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What if the machine doesn't have SSIS installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I have used in the past for easy deployments has been BIDS Helper.

[BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/)

May not be exactly what you need, but once your package is deployed, you can setup a SQL Agent Job to execute the package on a regular schedule.